# mysql complains about subquery in from for view

Tags: mysql, select, view, subquery

I was playing around in some sandbox code by dinking around with the warcraft auction API to test some mysql concepts, when I ran into a problem creating a desired view.
I have set up two tables, one for storing the actual data from blizzard, the second for keeping track of the 'lastModified' date stamps whenever I pull an update. Each auction entry is tagged with an 'updateId' which points to the other table with a given 'lastModified' tstamp. What I wanted to do was to write a view to find all the updateIds for the MAX(lastModified) and then return all of the auction records matching that updateId

I was able to get this query to work by splitting it into two views, but I was wondering if there is some way to condense it into a single view. The only syntax I am aware of is including the select under the 'from' clause but mysql doesn't seem to like that when creating views:

*mostRecentUpdates* view:

```
SELECT
  au.auctionUpdateId as auId,
  au.lastModified,
  au.realmId,
  au.house
 FROM
  `AuctionUpdates` AS au
 WHERE
  (
    au.`lastModified` = (
      SELECT
       MAX(lastModified)
       FROM
        `AuctionUpdates`
    )
  )
```

*mostRecentAuctions* view:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  mr.lastModified AS lastModified,
  mr.realmId AS realmId,
 FROM (
    Auctions AS a
   JOIN mostRecentUpdates AS mr
    ON (a.updateId = mr.auId)
  )
  ORDER BY
   a.updateId
```

If I drop the first select into the JOIN on the second, it won't save as a view. I'm just wondering if there's some other way to do this query so it can be condensed into a single view rather than two of them?

Answer (score 0):

You, you can write this as a single query, just using `join`s:

```
SELECT a.*,
       au.lastModified AS lastModified,
       au.realmId AS realmId,
FROM Auctions a join
     AuctionUpdates au
     ON a.updateId = mr.auId join
     (select auId, MAX(lastModified) as maxLastModified
      from AuctionUpdates au
      group by auId
     ) alm
     on au.LastModified = alm.maxLastModified and
        au.auId = alm.auId
ORDER BY a.updateId
```

The key is using a group by in a subquery to get the last modified date for each auction.  The rest is just joining in this information.

Does this work?

```
SELECT a.*,
       au.lastModified AS lastModified,
       au.realmId AS realmId,
FROM Auctions a join
     AuctionUpdates au
     ON a.updateId = mr.auId
where lastModified = (select max(LastModified)
                      from AuctionUpdates au2
                      where au.auID = au2.auID
                     )
ORDER BY a.updateId
```

Comment: yes, but that's what I first tried. I'm trying to create it as a view so I can save it for later reference. When you put the Select under the 'From', it complains and won't save it.

error 1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Comment: and I'm aware it does work that way - I was able to preview it fine, it just won't save that way.

Comment: @Scott . . . Now I remember that arcane and inexplicable restriction.  Explains why I don't use views in MySQL.  But, look at my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subqueries in views as long as you create your subquery as a view then reference that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally figured it out. Duh, it wasn't too difficult once I finally saw how to arrange it after going over the two queries a few more times:

```
SELECT
  a.*,
  au.lastModified,
  au.realmId
 FROM
   Auctions AS a
  INNER JOIN
    AuctionUpdates AS au
   ON
    au.auctionUpdateId = a.updateId
 WHERE
  (au.lastModified = (SELECT MAX(lastModified) FROM AuctionUpdates))
 ORDER BY
  a.updateId ASC
```

I just had the joins in the wrong order in my head. Join the two tables first then search for the ones that match the max rather than finding max then joining the results.